# facebook friends list in android using facebook api

Tags: java, android, facebook

How to access Facebook friends list in to our android application using Facebook API .

when i click a Facebook button it should ask user credentials after that it should display friends list of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [restfb](http://restfb.com/) (a client library for the graph API)

- authenticate with OAuth (facebook is forcing oauth everywhere now anyway)
- use the `/friends` connection - `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`

Answer (score 1):

you need to look this project and learn to use the api.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk